# Check WhatsApp numbers with PHP

Tags: php, node.js, whatsapp

How can I check WhatsApp phone numbers if they are available or not?

Is there a working example for this?

I will use PHP or any server side code to check numbers and get the last seen data.

I get this error with mgp25 s api

```
Array ( [cc] => 90 [in] => 5418444444 [lg] => tr [lc] => TR [id] => !`mè)lv���Լ,�!�0� [token] => VXqFr1tQChP8xtTzz4U2jxV8KWU= [mistyped] => 6 [network_radio_type] => 1 [simnum] => 1 [s] => [copiedrc] => 1 [hasinrc] => 1 [rcmatch] => 1 [pid] => 6840 [rchash] => 2f7edc328bc9f21ac98a8eb3d323dd1a7c104e7b0f49c0ffe66f9c2bb0ca9207 [anhash] => f4f4c4784c6166b69329839f38176700 [extexist] => 1 [extstate] => 1 [mcc] => 286 [mnc] => 000 [sim_mcc] => 286 [sim_mnc] => 000 [method] => sms ) stdClass Object ( [login] => 90544444444 [status] => fail [reason] => bad_token ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a problem trying to request the code.' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wp/src/Registration.php:316 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/wp/examples/exampleRegister.php(44): Registration->codeRequest('sms') #1 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/wp/src/Registration.php on line 316
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this WhatsApp unofficial API [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API).All documentation is available [here](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation).

Comment: is it working? because I used it and get old_version error

Comment: You need to see the updates log here (https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-incoming-updates) ,  and the issues reported here(https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/1534)

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of the  code on top of the Link?